# how to check if there is a duplicate string in repositorycombo box?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

how to check if there is a string already exist in repository
[image]

as you can see there's a duplicate dance in column genre. and when i click on auto filter row the dance got read twice. how to discard it there's a same string ?. so there's only one dance in the repositoryitembox

```
    private void gridView1_CustomRowCellEdit(object sender, CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e)
    {
        repositoryItemComboBox1.Items.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < gridView1.RowCount; i++)
        {
            var genre = gridView1.GetDataRow(i)["genre"].ToString();

            //if (genre.Contains("Dance"))
            //{
            //    repositoryItemComboBox1.Items.Add("!!!");
            //}
            repositoryItemComboBox1.Items.Add(genre);
        }
```

Edit :  i dont want to check by string as `genre.contains("Dance")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could simply done that by using Combobox1.Items.Contains function

```
        for (int i = 0; i < gridView1.RowCount; i++)
        {
            string genre = gridView1.GetDataRow(i)["genre"].ToString();

            // Check if the genre already existed or not
            if (!comboBox1.Items.Contains(genre))
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(genre);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't check against the string genre, but against the combobox items you already have. Therefore:

```
private void gridView1_CustomRowCellEdit(object sender, CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e)
{
    repositoryItemComboBox1.Items.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < gridView1.RowCount; i++)
    {
        var genre = gridView1.GetDataRow(i)["genre"].ToString();
        if(!repositoryItemComboBox1.Items.Contains(genre))
        {
            repositoryItemComboBox1.Items.Add(genre);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks,  it works
how silly am i without using "!"
hahaaha